# pyinstaller OwnerError

Tags: python, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I need to build a standalone exe which does not need python to be installed on the user's computer. I tried with nuitka, cx_freeze but they include also other files or in case with nuitka, it needs python to be installed on the client's computer. Im using python 2.7
This is the error i get when trying with pyinstaller:

```
python C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller.py --onefile C:\Users\root\Desktop\script.py



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 459, in doimport
    mod = director.getmod(nm)
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 248, in getmod
    mod = owner.getmod(nm)
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\archive.py", line 471, in getmod
    localpath: ExtInPkgImporter(localpath, nm)},
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\archive.py", line 491, in __init__
    iu.DirOwner.__init__(self, path)
  File "C:\Users\root\Desktop\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 82, in __init__
    raise OwnerError("%s is not a directory" % path)
iu.OwnerError: <OwnerError C:/Users/root/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI54282/ is not a directory>
```

Comment: Are you asking for help with pyinstaller specifically, or are you looking for alternatives?

Comment: According to the [pyinstaller issue tracker](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/597), this may be a known bug in your version of pyinstaller. Are you using the latest version because this has been marked completed about 9 months ago.

Comment: @amccormack thanks man you saved my life. i used the older version an it worked

Comment: you should answer your own question where you say what version you used when it worked. That way others will see how to fix this problem if they come across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error does not appear for me uising pyinstaller-1.5.1